# difference between using malloc and initializing directly to the stack in terms of memory space

Tags: c, memory, struct

I've been reading "Learn C the Hard Way" and I ran across an interesting problem that I was hoping someone could explain in detail. The basic exercise was to use a struct involving an example Person struct. In the first case, I had a constructor-ish method (I don't exactly get why the tutorial did it this way if someone wouldn't mind explaining on the side :D) along with the struct like this:

```
struct Person {
  char *name;
  int age;
  int height;
  int weight; 
};

struct Person *Person_create(char *name, int age, int height, int weight) 
{
  struct Person *who = malloc(sizeof(struct Person)); 
  assert(who != NULL);

  who->name = strdup(name);
  who->age = age; 
  who->height = height;
  who->weight = weight;
}
```

Along with rest of the code, this runs just fine, but when I print the memory location of the pointers to these structs like:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
     struct Person *joe = Person_create("joe alex", 12, 80, 100);
     struct Person *joe = Person_create("frank blank", 20, 72, 140);
}
```

The difference in their memory values are always exactly 40. In comparison, an implementation of the struct constructor like:

```
 struct Person{//is the same as above};

 struct Person Person_create (char* name, int age, int height, int weight) {
  struct Person newPerson;
  newPerson.name = name; //and so on

  return newPerson
 }
```

When I print out the memory locations of joe and frank, initialized with the same values as above, with the above implementation, the difference in their memory location appears to be always 20.

I studied a bit of assembly and I am aware that the compiler assigns blocks of memory according to the data types of the struct so I was thinking.. in either implementations, a char array has so many chars so n characters * 1 = char space, and then I have 3 ints so 3*4 = 12; 12 + 9 (Joe Alex\0 right?) = 21.. I probably got the \0 wrong so it's equal to 20 or something, but regardless of the specific memory size of my structs, I'm more interested in why the two different implementations result in a different size in memory (to my understanding, DOUBLE the memory cost is quite a significant amount).

Comment: Well, for a start, in the second example, you're not creating a copy of the strings...

Comment: Also, in the second case, your function is returning by value, so it's not clear what you mean by "memory locations".  Perhaps you could create a short self-contained example that we could compile to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: your `struct` comprises of 3 `int`s & one `char` pointer ~ so the size is probably 4+ (4*3) bytes. you can verify this by calling `sizeof`. ~a difference in memory locations is no sure way to determine the size of your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case 4 dynamic allocations are made: two name strings with `strdup`, and 2 Person structs with `malloc`. The difference between the struct addresses tells you roughly how much memory was allocated including the first struct, and before the second one[*]

In the second case, no dynamic allocations are made, but I imagine you've created two `Person` objects on the stack:

```
struct Person joe = Person_create("joe alex", 12, 80, 100);
struct Person frank = Person_create("frank blank", 20, 72, 140);
```

The difference between their addresses tells you roughly how much memory the first one occupies[*].

Since you haven't copied the strings, you're pretty much required to either use a string literal as the name, or else to manage its memory separately from the `Person` struct. The string data is *not* part of the `struct Person` -- never will be. `newPerson.name = name` just stores the *pointer*, not the string data.

This becomes a nuisance as soon as you start reading the names from a file or the terminal: you'll have to dynamically allocate them anyway, so you won't save any memory, but you'll have to write more code. The exercise probably includes a `Person_Destroy` function that `free`s the name, so that the user of `struct Person` doesn't have to worry about that separately.

[*] Except that the implementation isn't required to allocate these things one after the other, so your method doesn't work in general. It just happens to be giving results on this occasion consistent with the theory that the allocations are placed in the order you made them.

Comment: Thank you very much, I get it better now.

Answer (score 0):

The two methods vary greatly in the way they need to be used:

Define:
`struct Person *Person_create(char *name, int age, int height, int weight)`
Use:
`struct Person *p = Person_create(...);`
The `Person_create` function allocates the structure. The location where this structure will be depends on the function's implementation. The caller only needs to define a pointer to this memory, not a whole person structure.

Define:
`struct Person Person_create (char* name, int age, int height, int weight)`
Use:
`struct Person p = Person_create(...);`
Here, the caller allocated a whole person structure, not just a pointer. When the function is called, the data it returns will be copied into the caller's person structure. So the location of the structure depends on the caller.